# Adding hg strip to hgrc config file

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I have added strip extension hgrc config. (MAC OS)

```
cd ~
nano .hgrc
```

under `[extension]` added line:

```
strip =
```

Even vagrant restart or mac restart didn't help, the command is still not recognizable.

hgrc file:

```
[ui]
        # name and email, e.g.
        # username = Jane Doe <jdoe@example.com>
        username = ....>
        ignore=~/.hgignore_global

        # We recommend enabling tweakdefaults to get slight improvements to
        # the UI over time. Make sure to set HGPLAIN in the environment when
        # writing scripts!
        # tweakdefaults = True

        # uncomment to disable color in command output
        # (see 'hg help color' for details)
        # color = never

        # uncomment to disable command output pagination
        # (see 'hg help pager' for details)
        # paginate = never

        [extensions]
        uncomment these lines to enable some popular extensions
        (see 'hg help extensions' for more info)

        churn =
        color =
        strip =

        [color]
        status.modified = blue bold underline red_background
        status.added = green bold
        status.removed = red bold blue_background
        status.deleted = cyan bold underline
        status.unknown = magenta bold underline
```

Comment: Can you post the entire contents of your hgrc or at least the relevant portion?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Hey updated main topic with file content.

Comment: In the extensions section the comment is uncommented... Is this the issue?

Answer (score 5):

You should replace

```
    [extensions]
    uncomment these lines to enable some popular extensions
    (see 'hg help extensions' for more info)

    churn =
    color =
    strip =
```

with

```
    [extensions]
    # uncomment these lines to enable some popular extensions
    # (see 'hg help extensions' for more info)

    churn =
    color =
    strip =
```

(you uncommented both the actual extension-enable lines and the explanatory comment which was intended to stay commented out)